# ASP.NET Identity not working when deployed to web server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I created an asp.net mvc app. database first. I can log in and register using asp.net identity on my local machine. everything works fine. A soon as i deploy to my web server (internal), I cannot login or register. I get an error page from my mvc app with no explanation. I understand identity uses a local db "out of the box" for it's tables? How do I configure it to create tables in my sql database? Or do I need to manually create them? How do I configure Identity on my web server?

Update* My authentication mode in my web.config = "Windows"

Comment: What is on the error page?

Comment: well it takes about 2 minutes to load but when it finally does, I get the a default error page created in the mvc app that says" Error. An error occurred while processing your request."

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to create a SQL Database in Azure or somewhere, Change the Connection String, then you will migrate your DB (Assuming your using EF) by update-database command

Comment: I have an existing db in sql on the web server. it's a db I have been using for a separate app for a couple of years. I have tables/objects I want to use from that DB in my mvc app. I am doing DB first using EF. Is there a walk through on setting up identity/ Update Database command?

Comment: You need another DB to be use by your application. 
follow this basic steps and configure them for your need
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-model

To connect to your SQL Database, I suggest looking for the Connection String and changing it. 

You know if its right when you see the web sql can be seen in Server Explorer

Comment: I cannot use an existing database? What's the point of database first? I need to use my existing database.

Comment: Well in the case of Migration, it won't delete your current database but it is recommended to have an empty database.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on custom errors to see what's the actual error is. You can do that by adding this to web config.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I added that to my web.config. deployed again. I get the same error page.

Comment: According to your last update you are using Windows login right? I thought you were using Form Authentication. It may be something to do with IIS config for windows Authetication.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs

Comment: To the conversation bellow: If you are using form authentication you can always add required tables for ASP.NET Identities manually to your existing database. Depends on what version of ASP.NET identity you have the SQL varies, the latest one is https://gist.github.com/josephjeganathan/814c2031471b4c67df58